# How to loop in dynamic array using ngFor ?

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am trying to bind dynamic array to md-option. But it is throwing error.

```
                    <md-select id="hospital0{{index}}" placeholder="Hospital" style="width:100%; " name="hospital">
                      <md-option *ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList{{index}}" [value]="hospital.id">{{ hospital.name }}</md-option>
                    </md-select>
```

I tried another approach. In that I am fetching the select element and then adding options to it. But it is not adding option inside md-option.
This I have tried

```
    public async GetHospitalForCity(cityId: any) {
console.log(cityId);
let ddl = (<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById("hospital000"));
let option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "1";
option.text = "Hospital1";
ddl.appendChild(option);
```

}

Comment: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("" placeholder="Hospital" style="width:100%; " name="hospital">
                          <md-option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList{{index}}" [value]="hospital.id">{{ hospital.name }}</md-option>
"): ng:///AppModule/MrWeeklyPlanComponent.html@97:37
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 29 in [let hospital of hospitalList{{index}}] in ng:///AppModule/MrWeeklyPlanComponent.html@97:37 ("ame="hospital">

Comment: This error I am getting with the first approach.

Comment: I don't think you should use something like `hospitalList{{index}}`, because the template expression (with `{{}}`) will never be parsed.
Instead you should use this property inside your component : `hospitalList: Array<any[]>`, then you can use `*ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList[index]"` in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using:

```
ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList[index]"
```

as said by Elvynia in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Though the post is old, I add a similar problem and none of the above solutions  solved my problem.
But eventually I found out a solution as below.

We can have a function in ts which returns the array on index and bind it in template as below:

HTML:

```
*ngFor="let hospital of getArray(i+1); let i=index"
```

ts:

```
getArray(i: number): any[] {
  if (i === 1) {
     return this.hospital1;
  }else {
     return this.hospital2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the array inside the `ngFor` is async, you use the `async pipe` built in angular.

Example

```
<md-option *ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList{{index}} | async" [value]="hospital.id">
    {{ hospital.name }}
</md-option>
```

Comment: i added the example, you have to use the async pipe as i showed to get it working.

Comment: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("" placeholder="Hospital" style="width:100%; " name="hospital">
                          <md-option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let hospital of hospitalList{{index}} | async" [value]="hospital.id">{{ hospital.name }}</md-"): ng:///AppModule/MrWeeklyPlanComponent.html@97:37
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 29 in [let hospital of hospitalList{{index}} | async] in ng:///AppModule/MrWeeklyPlanComponent.html@97:37 ("pital">

Comment: It is not parsing the placeholder braces {{ }}